# Array without explicit size is not working inside another array? (re: lookup table)

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to define a USB HID ID to PS/2 Scan Code lookup with the following structure:

```
struct usbToPs2matrix_t {
  uint8_t hid_id;
  uint8_t ps2Make[];
  uint8_t ps2Break[];
};
```

The HID ID is a single value (ie. 0x19) but can have one or more MAKE and BREAK codes.

I'm initializing the array like this:

```
const usbToPs2matrix_t newMatrix[] = { 
   { 0x0, { }, { } },  // unused
   { 0x1, { }, { } },  // unused
   { 0x2, { }, { } },  // unused
   { 0x3, { }, { } },  // unused
   { 0x4, { 0x9E }, { 0xF0, 0x1C } }, 
   { 0x5, { 0xB0 }, { 0xF0, 0x32 } }, 
   ... };
```

I can't figure out a more efficient method, so I'm making sure the element position matches the HID ID, but when I access the ps2Make or ps2Break arrays they are incorrect:

```
PrintHex<uint8_t>(newMatrix[0x4]->ps2Make[0], 0x80);  // it doesn't print 0x9E
```

What am I doing wrong and can you suggest a more efficient lookup table structure?

Comment: C++ doesn't support flexible array members, so `uint8_t ps2Make[];` is not allowed

Comment: Arrays either need to be declared with a size, or declared with a list of items that the size is deduced from.  In this case since the size can be different, you want to ditch the array and use a `std::vector`

Comment: Arrays of unusual size? I don't think they exist.